# Issue inserting rows when using linq and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm fairly new to using Linq and Entity Framework but I am now attempting to insert rows into a SQL Server database (update rows is working correctly), but I can't get to the root cause of the following error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PurdisHeatingSolutions.NewCustomer' to 'PurdisHeatingSolutions.Customer'

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PurdisHeatingSolutions
{
    public partial class NewCustomer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Response.Redirect("~/Customers");
        }

        protected void CreateCustomerData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var context = new PurdisHeatingSolutions.PHSContext())
            {
                Guid guid = new Guid();

                NewCustomer cust = new NewCustomer
                                       {   
                                           CustomerId = guid,
                                           CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text.Trim(),
                                           CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text.Trim(),
                                           ContactNumber = txtCustomerNumber.Text.Trim(),
                                           ContactEmail = txtCustomerEmail.Text.Trim()
                                      };

                txtCustomerAddress.Text = cust.CustomerName;

                context.Customers.Add(cust);
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class NewCustomer
    {
        public NewCustomer() { }

        public NewCustomer(Guid customerId, string customerName, string customerAddress, string customerContact, string customerEmail)
        {
             CustomerId = customerId;
             CustomerName = customerName;
             CustomerAddress = customerAddress;
             ContactNumber = customerContact;
             ContactEmail = customerEmail;
        }

        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error occurs on line

```
context.Customers.Add(cust);
```

with the argument against the object cust.

I've checked the object items directly match the context `Customers`, but cannot work out why I'm receiving the issue.

Can anybody see why?

Comment: The error message tells you. The `Customers` DbSet is for Type `Customer` not `NewCustomer`

Comment: Great thank you, I appear to have mis-understood how that part works, now makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NewCustomer` class is the `System.Web.UI.Page` derived class whereas you want to create `Customer` model class objects and add them to your context. You should not mix this two classes by making them partial - `Customer` model should be a lightweight plain C# class with the properties only and no logic.